# MS SSAS 2008 and HTTP interface called msmdpump.dll

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, http-proxy, sql-server

I have following situation.

- Computer A is my user computer on which I work. On this computer I would like to use Excel and be able to connect to SSAS thru HTTP.
- Computer B is machine which holds IIS.
- Computer C is machine which holds SSAS.
- Computer A is under LAN A and ActiveDirectory A.
- Computers B and C are under LAN B and ActiveDirectory B.
- Computer A has access only to Computer B so that's why I have to use http proxy (msmdpump.dll) to get to Computer C.

SSAS is running as domain service account. I've set Computer B as "trusted for delegation" and ssas-domain service account as "trust this user for delegation to any service" and registered his SPN (http/hostname:81; http/hostname.domain:81).

When I try to connect to http url with Excel I get error. Also with SSMS I get error saying: unsupported data format.

With Excel I try to connect with Data-FromOtherSources-FromAnalysisServices. I type server name as http://server-ip:81/OLAP/msmdpump.dll and specify my domain credentials for LAN B I get: unable to connect to data source, reason, unable to locate database server.

But when I try to enter http://server-ip:81/OLAP/msmdpump.dll in browser I get soap fault which means it's successfully configured?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><faultcode>XMLAnalysisError.0xc10e0002</faultcode><faultstring>Parser: The syntax for 'GET' is incorrect.</faultstring><detail><Warning WarningCode="1090584599" Description="The 'Invariant Language' locale for UI is not supported." Source="Unknown" HelpFile=""/><Error ErrorCode="3238920194" Description="Parser: The syntax for 'GET' is incorrect." Source="Unknown" HelpFile=""/></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Also I forgot to mention that I have enabled only basic authentication in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I had anonymous authentication enabled, I've disabled it now.